# Which Canadian universities required Ancient Greek and Latin? From when to when?

Tags: canada, greek, latin-language

I limit this question to universities in Canada.

1.  What rough percentage of universities required Ancient Greek and Latin, for admission?

2. Then what about after admission, during university?

3. If 2 is true, to what difficulty or degree were these mandated  courses?

4. For both questions 1 and 2, would you please roughly date your answers (from when to when)?